# INSERT, SELECT, VALUES

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have table like this:-
(BL_SUBSCRIBER)

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -------
 MSISDN                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
 SUBSCRIBER_ID                             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
 BILLING_ID                                         VARCHAR2(20)
 SUB_TYPE                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 SUB_TYPE_EXTRA                                     VARCHAR2(20)
 LANGUAGE                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 TIME_RESTRICT_FLAG                        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)
```

and table like this:-

(BL_SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE)

```
MSISDN                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
PACKAGE_SEQ                    NOT NULL NUMBER(8)
ID                             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
OBJTYPE                        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
TYPE                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
```

I want to fill the table ***BL_SUBSCRIBER*** with the MSISDN from ***BL_SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE***
and at the same time , I want to fill the other columns (NOT NULL) with any data, 
I tried the following

```
insert into BL_SUBSCRIBER (
MSISDN,
SUBSCRIBER_ID,
SUB_TYPE,
LANGUAGE)
values (
select MSISDN from BL_SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE,
sub_id_seq.nextval,   //sub_id_seq is a sequence already defined.
'prepaid',
'EN')
```

but it gives me errors(missing expression)
SO, can anyone tell me how to copy data from one table to another and insert the default needed data (in this case it is must because it is NOT NULL).
PS:I'm Using Oracle Database
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try

```
insert into BL_SUBSCRIBER (MSISDN,SUBSCRIBER_ID,SUB_TYPE,LANGUAGE)
    select
        MSISDN,
        sub_id_seq.nextval,   //sub_id_seq is a sequence already defined.
        'prepaid',
        'EN'
    from BL_SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE;
```

Also check out @a_horse_with_no_name answer below for some useful Oracle documentation links - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27851367/1466341

Comment: @DarkSide  thanks for your attention, I  tried the following, and it gives me not enough values 

```CREATE SEQUENCE sub_id_seq
  MINVALUE 1
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  NOCACHE;
  
  
insert into bl_subscriber (MSISDN,
SUBSCRIBER_ID,
SUB_TYPE,
LANG,
TIME_RESTRICT_FLAG,
RATING_PLAN,
ROAM_VOL_LIMIT,
FINAL_THRESHOLD_ACTION,
ROAM_FLAG)
select MSISDN,
to_char(sub_id_seq.NEXTVAL),
'10',
'EN',
'N',
10240,
1,
'N'
from bl_subscriber_package;```

Comment: @IbrahimSalama - that is significantly different from the question; but that has nine columns and only eight expressions. As the error suggests. Count the terms. Also why make your sequence value into a string?

Comment: @DarkSide  because the subscriber_id is defined in the Database as a string, thanks , I appreciate your help.

Comment: @DarkSide the query works fine now , but it doesn't accept the `sequence number`, can you tell me how to generate a unique id each row ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not sure why SQLFiddle says that SQL command is not properly ended, but `INSERT INTO t(...) SELECT ... FROM t2` is correct syntax.

Comment: Yes, now that you removed the `values` clause and the `(...)` around the select, it *is* correct. Until then it was not.

Comment: I know, but still this syntax doesn't work in SQLFiddle. Stange, but it looks like some SQLFiddle bug.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a `select` as the source for an `insert` you don't need the `values`:

```
insert into BL_SUBSCRIBER (MSISDN,SUBSCRIBER_ID,SUB_TYPE,LANGUAGE)
select MSISDN 
       sub_id_seq.nextval, 
       'prepaid',
       'EN'
from BL_SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE;
```

As usual the correct syntax is documented in the manual: 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF55051

and it also has an example for this:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF55103

Comment: thanks for your feedback, I tried something like that, and it gives me not enough values,

Comment: @IbrahimSalama: then you are not showing us the code that you run. The number of columns in the `insert` list must match the number of columns in the `select` list (as it does in my answer)